# Access Try-Catch block's code in another class

Tags: java, exception

May be it could be silly,but I want to clear my the technical understanding of this code:

```
import netscape.*;//ldap jar
public class A {

    public void method() {
        ...

        try {
            //code is written here.
             LDAPSearchResults lsr = ldi.search(LDAPConnectionInfo.MY_SEARCHBASE,LDAPConnectionInfo.MY_SCOPE,LDAPConnectionInfo.MY_FILTER,null,false);
             while(lsr.hasMoreElements()){
             LDAPEntry findEntry = (LDAPEntry)lsr.nextElement();

        } catch(...) { 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Now I call another class

```
public class B {
    A a = new A();
    //here I want to use attributeName 
}
```

- How could I access A class's member(in try block) in B class.
- Any way to handle try block code for reuse in another class.
- How could I handle all those exception in another class.

Any modification should I need...

Calling method of Object type.

```
public class C{
private String attributeName;

   public String getAttributeName() {
       return attributeName;
   }

public Object method(){
attributeName=lAttribute.getName(); 
}
}
```

- How could print this Object type method into String(in a jsp page)... any inputs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need a member in class `A` and a getter:

```
public class A {
   private String attributeName;

   public String getAttributeName() {
       return attributeName;
   }

   public void method(){
        ...

        try {
            //code is written here.
            attributeName = lAttribute.getName(); 
        }
        catch() { 
        } 
   } 
}
```

Then:

```
public class B {
    A a = new A();

    // somewhere
    String str = a.getAttributeName();
}
```

There's no way to access a method's private variables like you did in the original example, as they only exist on the stack during the method call.

**Edit**: I noticed another question:

> How could I handle all those exception in another class.

I assume you want to call your method somewhere else and catch the exceptions there. In that case you can use the `throws` keyword to communicate that your method will pass exceptions to the caller:

```
public class A {

    public void method() throws IOException {

        //code is written here.
        String attributeName = lAttribute.getName(); 
    } 

    public void anotherMethod() {
        try {
            method();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ...
        } 
    }
}
```

then if some other piece of code calls `method` it will be forced to either handle or further propagate the exception.

Comment: @big zero: So did you try what I posted? To create a member variable.

Comment: thanks for your reply,but I'm using my code like this & have edited my question... any modification should I need.

Comment: @big zero: You can do it the same way, except you need to declare a member of type `LDAPEntry` instead of `String`.

Comment: But LDAPEntry is the default class comes with that netscape.*,still I should go with you method....?

Comment: @big zero: It doesn't matter. You can use this method for any type.

Comment: If you write public string method() & this method's return getAttributeName;then what willbe the difference in a.getAttributeName;Could you tell me.

Comment: @big zero: In that case you don't even need `getAttributeName` and the field `attributeName` in the class. You can just build the string inside the method and return it like `String str = a.method();`

Comment: what'll be the benefit of return in this case

Comment: @big zero: The benefit is that you don't need the extra global variable `attributeName`. The method will be self-contained without assigning anything to a global state. It's better to use return in this case.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your clarification against my silly question and I have edited my question little bit,could you take a look of it

Answer (score 1):

> How could I handle all those exception in another class.

In your calling class you can catch Throwable (which will catch all exceptions and errors)

```
try {
....
}
catch (Throwable t) {
//do something with the throwable.
}
```

if you do not want to catch Errors (Ive only done this when messing around with ImageIO and had memory problems) in Java then catch Exception instead

> Any way to handle try block code for reuse in another class

here you could create a method in another class and then call it within your try /catch block

```
public class XYX {
    public void methodForTry() throws Exception {
    //do something
    }
}


try {
    new XYZ().methodForTry();
}
catch (Exception e){
}
```

You may or may not want to create new XYZ here. It depends what state this object may or may not hold.

As to the last questions I think Tudor's answer covers this

Answer (score 1):

Your question may be about extracting the code template

```
try { ... do stuff ... } 
catch (MyFirstException e) { ...handle ... }
catch (MySecondException e) { ...handle ... }
... more catch ...
```

Where you only want to change the `... do stuff ...` part. In that case you'd need *closures*, which are coming with Java 8, and today you'd need something quite cumbersome, of this sort:

```
public static void tryCatch(RunnableExc r) {
  try { r.run(); } 
  catch (MyFirstException e) { ...handle ... }
  catch (MySecondException e) { ...handle ... }
  ... more catch ...
}
```

where `RunnableExc` would be an

```
interface RunnableExc { void run() throws Exception; }
```

and you'd use it this way:

```
tryCatch(new RunnableExc() { public void run() throws Exception {
   ... do stuff ...
}});
```

Comment: your code on this context is worthy to be appreciated,but I'm using sdk 1.6.0.35 :( :(

Comment: in my Ques,3rd block of code is given,could you share your idea how does it can be achieved...

Answer (score 1):

why not `return` it?

```
public String method() {
String attributeName
    try {
        //code is written here.
        attributeName = lAttribute.getName(); 
    } catch(...) { 
    } 
return attributeName;
}


public class B {
A a = new A();
String attributeName = a.method();
}
```